# Physician assistant school rescinded my acceptance

Tags: interpersonal-issues, communication, work-life-balance

I'm in a complicated situation. I was accepted to physician assistant school and was told I'm one of the most qualified candidates. I'm also a mother of 2 children (under age 3) and living with their father who doesn't want me to go to PA school (because I'll have more freedom).  But not only is he physically and emotionally abusive, but he stopped paying for my cell phone and started throwing away my mail (from my school and everyone else)  to limit my communication with anyone. (Note: I'm three months postpartum and have stayed home to care for my kids  waiting for school to start, and have no income of my own). I communicated this problem with my school via email as they could not reach me by phone. Even though it was embarrassing, I gave them specifics of my circumstances. Yet I Iived up to my promise to keep up with their other requirements.

Yesterday, I was shocked to learn that they rescinded my acceptance because I couldn't be reached by phone during the last month (but did respond to all correspondence via email). I explained the extenuating circumstances, and even presented evidence from police reports proving what was happening at home.

To make matters worse, my parents and I signed a lease on an apartment a block from school and agreed to help me pay for it so I could have a stable living environment with less distractions (constantly wondering if I would be forced onto the streets out of my abusive partner's apartment). We already signed a lease for the apartment.

I know that I honestly put forth my best effort to fulfill pre-matriculation requirements and to communicate with the only means I had (the computer). I couldn't go in person because I have no car. Graduating from this program was my ticket  to financial freedom out of this oppressive situation, and I feel like this school is going way too far to rescind my acceptance based ONLY on the short term termination of my phone.

How can I get the school to remake their offer?

Comment: My edit drops the _why_ part of your question (from the title), since you've answered that youreself. I've also dropped the _is it justified_ aspect, since that's subjective. I've added a new question, namely, _How can I get the school to remake their offer?_, which I think is what you want. Please revert/revise my edits, if you see fit.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. While I commiserate with you for your situation, I fail to see how we can help you in any way. This is something you have to take out with that school. Since this is a highly specific situation, we (and everybody else on the Internet) also cannot divine why exactly the school decided the way it did. And even if we could make an educated guess, it would just be that. Finally, the institution in question does not appear to be an academic one (correct me if I am wrong), so we cannot apply our general knowledge of academic rules and procedures.

Comment: You need to get a cheap phone [or just a SIM] that does not have a contract, such as pay-as-you-go, that you won't need to top up, just to receive calls on. I have a phone that I've not topped up in years, as I never call anyone, but I can still receive calls on it.

Comment: As other comments say, no one here can help with a precise recommendation. I think you should try to talk in person to someone at the school. Is there a local legal aid society where you might be able to get some pro bono legal advice, or at least someone to help you negotiate? In parallel, is there a reliable place (public or private) to get help dealing with the abusive relationship? That's important.

Comment: Deleted the "graduate admissions" tag because "physician assistant" does not require a graduate degree.  It's probably an associates degree.

Comment: @Greenonline A phone that has no contract, SIM, or Pay-as-you-go can still contact emergency services in some places.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist - What relevance does contacting emergency services have with the OP receiving acceptance offers by phone? A phone that has no SIM can not receive calls from other callers.

Comment: @Greenonline People in abusive relationships have a lot of emergencies.

Answer (score 4):

- Your highest priority should be getting safe from abuse.  We're not experts on that, so please contact a local authority. 
  [Here is a list.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_domestic_violence_hotlines)  You may be able to get help without using a phone.
- Becoming a physician assistant is not the only way out of your difficulties.  So don't panic about your acceptance.  Higher education does exist to help people like you, but there are many ways to get education.
- Contact the Director of Admissions for the Physician Assistant Program and explain your situation to them.  They will want to help you.  If you cannot find this person, try the Dean of Students.  If you cannot find them either, look for an Omsbudsperson.  Your admissions problem sounds like it is caused by disorganization.  If you contact the right person they will fix the problem.  Since we do not know which school you are talking about, we cannot tell you exactly who to contact.
- Ask local doctors what they think about this program before you start it.  Not all medical training programs are good.

Answer (score -1):

Someone already mentioned this, but the best course of action is find a lawyer. They can discuss specifics with you and you may have a good case for a lawsuit. At the very least, a lawyer can tell you what your options are in this situation and maybe even just a letter from an attorney may be enough change their minds.

Comment: This problem is almost certainly caused by human error on the part of the school, and can very likely be resolved by asking the right person to help.  I wouldn't involve a lawyer until this was discussed with the correct administrator.